# Basic math question about batches vs totals and remainders

Tags: arithmetic

I am struggling helping my little brother with a math question and its a bit embarrassing so I am hoping I can find some help here.

We are trying to resolve a problem as follows

A total number X should be divided by a known number Y but because it may not be an even split we also need to know the remainder Z

for example X=100, Y=10 yields 100/10=10 and Z is 0

but what if X=110 and Y=50 how can we understand that the answer is 2 and Z=10 ?

Answer (score 0):

What is the next multiple of Y below X and what is the difference of the multiple and X is a basic explaination.

What is the next multiple of 50 under 110? 100. What is the difference between 110 and 100? 10.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to write a *division statement*. This is an equation of the form $X=kY+Z$. In your first example you have $100=10\cdot 10+0=10\cdot 10$, while in your second you have $110=2\cdot 50+10=100+10$. The calculation technique used here is what's taught at "long divion." If you like, and the numbers are small enough, you can find $k$ by trial and error, and then find $Z$.